# Why would taxonomy_term_save be slow when called from hook_install_tasks?

Tags: taxonomy-terms, deployment, installation-profiles

As part of making a site more easily deployable from scratch, I have generated two PHP scripts to pre-populate taxonomy vocabularies with a list of terms.  The scripts are straightforward, creating `stdClass` objects with the appropriate fields and calling`taxonomy_term_save` on each one.  Example:

```
$term = (object) array (
  'name' => 'Art & Architecture',
  'description' => '',
  'format' => 'plain_text',
  'weight' => '0',
  'vocabulary_machine_name' => 'categories',
  'field_cc_numeric_code' =>
  array (
    'und' =>
    array (
      0 =>
      array (
        'value' => '102',
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
$term->vid = $vocabulary->vid;
taxonomy_term_save($term);
```

The variable `$vocabulary` already contains the appropriate taxonomy vocabulary structure at the time this is called.  One vocabulary has about 150 terms to create, the other about 2,000.

On a fresh installation of the site made using `drush site-install`, these scripts run almost instantly when called via `drush php-script`.  However, if they are incorporated into the installation profile and called by a task in the implementation of `hook_install_tasks`, they are much slower.  In the latter case, saving each term takes about a second, which is unacceptably slow.

There is discussion of a similar issue at https://www.drupal.org/node/1887924, but no solution offered either there or in the [linked bug report](https://www.drupal.org/node/1901690).

Why would `taxonomy_term_save` be so much slower when performed from an installation task?  Is there anything that can be done about it?

Comment: Profiling using XDebug suggests that the problem is a bad interaction with the `pathauto` module.  The bulk of execution time is spent in `pathauto_taxonomy_term_insert`, and omitting Pathauto from the enabled modules in the installation profile returns things to normal speed.  It is still unclear to me why this would be slow in an install hook but not otherwise.  If I can come up with a clean solution I will post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case, the problem resulted from having the [Pathauto](https://www.drupal.org/project/pathauto) module enabled during installation.  When a new taxonomy term is saved, Drupal calls `pathauto_taxonomy_term_insert()`, which calls `pathauto_taxonomy_term_update_alias()`, which in turn calls `pathauto_create_alias()`.  This last function calls an internal function, `_pathauto_path_is_callback()`, to determine whether an alias can be created for a given path, and this in turn calls the core function `menu_get_item()`, which contains the following lines:

```
if (variable_get('menu_rebuild_needed', FALSE) || !variable_get('menu_masks', array())) {
  menu_rebuild();
}
```

`menu_rebuild` contains the following lines:

```
if (defined('MAINTENANCE_MODE')) {
  variable_set('menu_rebuild_needed', TRUE);
}
else {
  variable_del('menu_rebuild_needed');
}
```

The cumulative effect seems to be that the `menu_rebuild_needed` variable is continually reset to `TRUE`, meaning that a complete menu rebuild is triggered each time a new taxonomy term is saved, slowing things down immensely (from ~100 terms saved per second to ~1 per second).

This seems like a bug, though it's not clear which component, if any, is at fault.  For now, I am working around the problem by disabling `pathauto`, creating the terms, and then re-enabling `pathauto`:

```
module_disable(array('pathauto'));
…
module_enable(array('pathauto'));
```

Comment: Possibly useful note: I used the [XDebug Profiler](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) and [qcachegrind](http://kcachegrind.sourceforge.net/html/Home.html), installed through MacPorts, to debug this.